# Search directory for a directory with certain files?

Tags: python

I'd like to search a folder recursively for folders containing files names "x.txt" and "y.txt". For example, if it's given `/path/to/folder`, and `/path/to/folder/one/two/three/four/x.txt` and `/path/to/folder/one/two/three/four/y.txt` exist, it should return a list with the item `"/path/fo/folder/one/two/three/four"`. If multiple folders within the given folder satisfy the conditions, it should list them all. Could this be done with a simple loop, or is it more complex?

Comment: This could be done with a recursive function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.walk` does the hard work of recursively iterating over a directory structure for you:

```
import os

find = ['x.txt', 'y.txt']

found_dirs = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/folder'):
    if any(filename in files for filename in find):
        found_dirs.append(root)

#found_dirs now contains all of the directories which matched
```